# How do I create Rows and Columns in jQuery after pulling data from a Share Point List

Tags: javascript, jquery, multiple-columns, rows

I created an accordion in JavaScript that contains 7 categories,I am also pulling data from a Share Point list and filtered the items by category. After filtering the items by its category and append it to its respective category panel I want to create 4 columns and whatever rows necessary with the items pulled from the list. The desired end result is attached.

The desired end result is attached. 
[Accordion Desired Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sy7dS.jpg)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://bc-net/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('specialDiscounts')/items",
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json; odata=verbose'
    },
    success: function (data) {
      var items = data.d.results;
      console.log(items);

       var auto = $('#automotive');
       var entertainment = $('#entertainment');
       var healthBeauty = $('#healthBeauty');
       var travel = $('#travel');
       var electronics= $('#electronics');
       var services= $('#services');
       var housing= $('#housing');


      for (var j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {

       var panelsContent ='<div class="row animated fadeInUp">' +
                        '<div class="col-md-4">' +
                        '<div class="card-body card-body-cascade text-center">' +
                        '<a href=" ' + items[j].Link.Url + '" target = _blank> <h4 class="card-title my-4"><strong>' + items[j].Title +
                        '</strong></h4></a><p class="card-text">' + items[j].Description + '</p>'                   



        // branching logic,
        // append the <p> in different places based on
        // different possible Category values

        switch (items[j].Category) {
            case 'Automotive':
                auto.append(panelsContent);
                break;
            case 'Entertainment':
                entertainment.append(panelsContent);
                break;
            case 'Health and Beauty':
                healthBeauty.append(panelsContent);
                break;
             case 'Travel':
                travel.append(panelsContent);
                break;
             case 'Electronics':
                electronics.append(panelsContent);
                break;
            case 'Services':
                services.append(panelsContent);
                break;
             case 'Housing':
                housing.append(panelsContent);
                break;
         default:
                break;
                }
    }

      },
    error: function (data) {
      alert('Error: ' + data);
    }
  }) // End Service Icons  //End Service Icons
}) // End ready function
```

This is a piece of the HTML

```
<div id="housing" class="accordion-content list-reset leading-normal px-8 py-4 hidden">
<!--Services Content Injected--> 
</div>
```

This is what I am getting
[This is what I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQ8AB.jpg)

[Console Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdHs3.jpg)

Comment: I assume you're using bootstrap by evidence of the col-md-4.  Based on limit knowledge of bootstrap but seeing this [bootstrap grid examples](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/examples/grid/) should you actually be using col-md-3 and have 4 of those inside each row?  Seems what you're getting is one col-md-4 in each row which is basically 1/3 width.

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle.  Make sure you resize the output screen to see the col classes take effect.  [https://jsfiddle.net/q31fd4nj/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/q31fd4nj/1/)

Comment: @sourkrause what I am getting on the console is 4 rows even though I changed the bootstrap class you mentioned, so I believe the problem lays on the looping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the most efficient way of doing it but it should work, or close to.  Basically, since your list of items could be of any category you want to build the content for each category as you loop through and not append that content to the accordion section until you're all done.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$.ajax({
    url: "http://bc-net/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('specialDiscounts')/items",
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json; odata=verbose'
    },
    success: function (data) {
        var items = data.d.results;
        console.log(items);

        var auto = $('#automotive');
        var entertainment = $('#entertainment');
        var healthBeauty = $('#healthBeauty');
        var travel = $('#travel');
        var electronics = $('#electronics');
        var services = $('#services');
        var housing = $('#housing');

        var autoContent = $('<div class="row animated fadeInUp"></div>');
        var entertainmentContent = $('<div class="row animated fadeInUp"></div>');
        var healthBeautyContent = $('<div class="row animated fadeInUp"></div>');
        var travelContent = $('<div class="row animated fadeInUp"></div>');
        var electronicsContent = $('<div class="row animated fadeInUp"></div>');
        var servicesContent = $('<div class="row animated fadeInUp"></div>');
        var housingContent = $('<div class="row animated fadeInUp"></div>');


        var itemContent;
        for (var j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {

            itemContent = '<div class="col-md-3">' +
                '<div class="card-body card-body-cascade text-center">' +
                '<a href=" ' + items[j].Link.Url + '" target = _blank> <h4 class="card-title my-4"><strong>' + items[j].Title +
                '</strong></h4></a><p class="card-text">' + items[j].Description + '</p></div></div>';

            // branching logic,
            // append the <p> in different places based on
            // different possible Category values

            switch (items[j].Category) {
                case 'Automotive':
                    autoContent.append(itemContent);
                    break;
                case 'Entertainment':
                    entertainmentContent.append(itemContent);
                    break;
                case 'Health and Beauty':
                    healthBeautyContent.append(itemContent);
                    break;
                case 'Travel':
                    travelContent.append(itemContent);
                    break;
                case 'Electronics':
                    electronicsContent.append(itemContent);
                    break;
                case 'Services':
                    servicesContent.append(itemContent);
                    break;
                case 'Housing':
                    housingContent.append(itemContent);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        auto.append(autoContent);
        entertainment.append(entertainmentContent);
        healthBeauty.append(healthBeautyContent);
        travel.append(travelContent);
        electronics.append(electronicsContent);
        services.append(servicesContent);
        housing.append(housingContent);

    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert('Error: ' + data);
    }
}); // End Service Icons  //End Service Icons
}); // End ready function
```